# averaging multiple columns in awk excluding null value

Tags: awk, null, average

I need to average all the columns in this file from column 3 to the last, excluding row 1:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY7W3.jpg)

```
jd h 3 5 8 10 11 14 15
79 1 52.0 51.0 58.0 45.0 59.0 20.0 27
79 2 52.0 51.0 58.0 45.0 59.0 20.0 -999.0
79 3 52.0 51.0 58.0 45.0 59.0 20.0 -999.0
79 4 -999.0 51.0 58.0 45.0 59.0 20.0 -999.0
```

<sup>*Data transcribed by [Chet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1087300/chet).*</sup>

This script works fine:

```
cat myfile.txt | awk ' NR>1{for (i=3;i<=NF;i++){a[i]+=$i;}} END {for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) {print a[i]/(NR-1)}}' > myoutput.txt
```

the problem is that in the columns I have null values (marked as "-999.0"), which I want to exclude from the average.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Please add the example file as text to the question, so that we can test with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'NR > 1 { for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++) if ($i != -999.0) { sum[i] += $i; num[i]++; } }
     END    { for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++) print i, sum[i], num[i], sum[i]/num[i] }' \
    myfile.txt > myoutput.txt
```

This counts only the valid field values, and counts the number of such rows for each column separately.  The printing at the end identifies the field, the raw data (sum, number) and the average.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked perfectly